# SAML between existing account and service provider

Tags: authentication, saml, saml-2.0

**Background:** 
I have a basic user database with username(email) and password. The users are able to sign in to a website of mine with these credentials. From the website they get a link to different services they have access to, but with different username/passwords. So they click the link "Open My Service X" and they have to login with their service unique login credentials. I do have the users service login-username. So I can map local-user <=> service-user.

I want SSO between service X which has support for SAML and my website.

**Question/Problem:**
I want the users to login with their user/password in my database, then single sign on towards service X where service X has support for SAML. I don't want a user to be able to sign up for a new user account to my website using the SAML support in service X. The user must already have an account in my database.

So my question might be rather vague, but I'm having a hard time to grasp how this can be achieved?

I was thinking of letting my webapp become a SAML identity provider, so that the SSO request are transferred back to my webapp and verified for their service-user. Would that be correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with your `SAML` `IdP`. There are basically three parts involved. Your email database (the identities), your existing application front end and the remote services which support `SAML`. Usually it's `SAML2` these days.

To get single sign-on (`SSO`) across your portfolio of apps (your own app and the remote services) you could install an `IdP` like the [`Shibboleth` IdP](https://www.shibboleth.net/products/identity-provider/) and convert your app to use it instead of using email/password to login. That would take a fair amount of work as you'd have to convert your app into a SAML SP, just like the remote services.

An easier way might be to only use the IdP for SAML to the remote services and get the IdP to recognise that your users are already logged in with their email/password. Cookie? So the IdP should never display a login page as it would recognise your app's cookie and match that with a user in the database. It then releases SAML attributes to the remote service based on that user's information. That also covers your use case of not allowing account creation via SAML from a remote service.

That would mean you might end up with the following URLs:

- https://yourapp.com/
- https://yourapp.com/idp/

Your users login with the first URL as normal and the remote services use the second URL. That way your app cookie will be visible to the /idp endpoint but you'd need to write code to match that with a user in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I will investigate this further.